# How to publicly verify contents of a database

Tags: mysql, database, cryptography, verification

I'm in the starting stages of a web-dev project and have run into a problem.

**Context:** The project/service will harvest and crunch data from multiple public, open sources. The data covers statistics and records of political activity, voting, and the like.

**Problem:** While the data itself can be referenced back to its source, I am worried that a database administrator could tamper with the data in the database. Since the data is of public interest, I need some public tamper-evidence on the database. My question is then how to do this.

I have been toying with ideas of how to go about this, such as giving the harvester a signing key so that it can sign its own imports, or some other method of cryptographic verification. Admin changes to the database would require vetting by some trusted third party, and circumventing this would invalidate the signatures somewhere, proving that tampering has taken place. The issue is that these systems somehow need to be kept out of reach of the server admin (root), so that there can be no suspicion of data tampering.

In brief, I need some system which will allow public verification of database contents and which cannot be circumvented, even by root.

The technical specifications are likely to use a simple LAMP-stack, so a solution should work with these systems.

Answer (score 0):

Are the harvesters separate from your service? If so, then I agree that some manner of verification is necessary as both the database administrator and the harvester itself could tamper with the information.

If the harvesters themselves are part of your service then I am not sure that you need to provide a "untampered" stamp. This case boils down to trust, publicly accessible data with back-references to sources enables all of your data consumers to independently verify the presented data.

Additionally, any such tool to verify the integrity of the data has to also be subjected to public scrutiny, after all the tool may just be implemented as such:

```
fn(source, data) -> True -- An implementation, just not a good one...
```

So in either case you are either asking your audience to:

A. Verify the data by comparing with the source, which all consumers are capable of
B. Verify the validity of your source-code, which requires technical expertise

Since B does not exclude A and you are determined to provide B I'd suggest using either a block chain https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_chain_%28database%29 and consider each data-modification a transaction. Or look at IPFS and its approach to hashing https://github.com/ipfs/ipfs

PGP signing may also be appropriate.

Comment: The harvesters will indeed be part of the service, which will be open source, and therefore open to public inspection. As will any verification system.

I agree that it is a matter of trust, and back-references may be sufficient, but I would like to have more-or-less a single, simple check any user could to to verify data validity. I'll be looking into a block-chain transaction approach. PGP signing presents some difficulty since it's not natively supported by PHP, but I'll look further into that too.